Formula for Root Series
Given the series:
$S_n=\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{c-1}+\sqrt{c-2}+\sqrt{c-3}+...+\sqrt{c-n}$ in which $c$ can be any value but independent from n.
Is there a formula for these kinds of series? Excluding the Summation of course.
The closes formula I got is by letting $f(x)=\sqrt{c-x}$ for which by integrating from $1$ to $n$ we'll have $S_n \approx - \frac{2}{3}(c-n)^\frac{3}{2}+\frac{2}{3}(c-1)^\frac{3}{2}$

No, there is no formula for that sum.

Is the last term $\sqrt{c-n}$ or $\sqrt{c+n}$ given that in all other terms you subtract form $c$? Or perhaps you wanted to write $\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{c+1}+\sqrt{c+2}+\ldots$

Oh sorry, my mistake, it should be $\sqrt{c-n}$

So $c\ge n$? Otherwise you have a negative number under the square roots.

A complex number is totally fine. Since you mentioned it, I am interested in how the formula will look like when $c \leq n$

No, a complex number is not totally fine.  The reason for this is that in complex analysis, totally unlike real analysis, for any $~z \in \Bbb{C_{\neq 0}},~$ the expression $~\sqrt{z}~$ is ambiguous.  This is   specifically because it represents $~w~$ where $~w~$ is any one of the two solutions of the equation $~w^2 = z.$

Re my previous comment, authors of complex analysis books, who wish to remove any ambiguity in the expression of $\displaystyle \sqrt{z} ~: ~z \in \Bbb{C_{\neq 0}},~$ do so by some artificial convention, that is consistently applied throughout the textbook.  One such convention is to express $~z = re^{i\theta} ~: r \in \Bbb{R^+}, ~-\pi < \theta \leq \pi,~$ and then adopt the convention that $~\displaystyle \sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r} \times e^{i\theta/2}.~$  Here $~\displaystyle \sqrt{r}~$ refers to the unique value $~s \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ such that $~s^2 = r.$

Let $x = c-n$. Then the sum is rewritten as
$$S(x,n) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}(x+i)^{1/2}$$`
If $x$ is positive, then the sum is
$$S(x,n) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}(x+i)^{1/2}= \zeta(-1/2,x)-\zeta(-1/2,x+n+1)$$
If $x=0$, simply take $S(x,n-1)$
If $x<0$, you have to define what $\sqrt{x}$ means
